# Problemas con button de material design de google

Tags: javascript, html5, material-design-lite, materialize

Tengo un `button` para subir imágenes en mi proyecto web; en Chrome y Microsoft Edge funciona, pero en Firefox no. Al dar clic debería de abrir la ventana para buscar la imagen a subir como lo hace en los otros navegadores.

Mi código HTML:

```
<button data-upgraded=",MaterialButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored f-left">
<i class="material-icons ">cloud_upload</i>
    <form method="POST" action="http://timeline.dev/post/ajaxupload" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="x-uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="_token" value="3kpNrTDVx59bdv1KqB8x4HNbftxdDC1TpIjpNgeX" type="hidden">
      <input name="file" type="file">
    </form>
</button>
```

Ese código debería de funcionar igual como lo hace en Chrome y Explorer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto es un problema que ocurre porque el código HTML no es válido. En la [definición de HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-button-element) se indica que el contenido dentro de un botón puede ser:

> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Es decir, contenido de tipo frase, pero que no sea interactivo. Y dentro de [contenido interactivo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2) se incluyen (entre otros): `a`, `button`, `select` o `input` que no sea `hidden` (enfasis añadido por mí):

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
>
> - a (if the href attribute is present), audio (if the controls attribute is present), button, details, embed, iframe, img (if the usemap attribute is present), **input (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state)**, keygen, label, object (if the usemap attribute is present), select, textarea, video (if the controls attribute is present)

En tu código incluyes un `form` y un `input` de tipo `file` dentro de un `button` que hace que el código no sea válido, entonces cada navegador lo interpretará como pueda. Chrome e IE lo interpretan de una manera que a ti te gusta y Firefox de una que no te gusta... pero podría ser de otra manera.

Una manera de solucionar el problema es hacer que el código sea válido:

- moviendo el formulario fuera,
- añadiendo un `id` al input del fichero, y
- cambiando el `button` por un `label` que apunte al `input` (con  un `for`).

Entonces el código será válido y funciona en todos los navegadores:

```html
<form method="POST" action="http://timeline.dev/post/ajaxupload" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="x-uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label data-upgraded=",MaterialButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored f-left" for="file">
    <i class="material-icons ">cloud_upload</i>
    <input name="_token" value="3kpNrTDVx59bdv1KqB8x4HNbftxdDC1TpIjpNgeX" type="hidden">
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file">
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono tal cual como queria.